# rails old model still in console after delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rake

So I just started a ruby project and I am quite new to rails. I want to create two models in my app; `Words` (like 'bike') and `Wordtypes` (like 'noun'). I first generate the Word model through a scaffold.

```
  $ rails g scaffold Word word_name:string word_type_name:string
  $ rake db:migrate
```

I then remind myself that it might be better not to use a `word_type_name` and that it might be better to use a `word_type_id` instead so I can communicate that with another database that contains the wordtype references. .

So I then run:

```
  $ rails destroy scaffold Word
  $ rake db:migrate
```

And I create the whole thing anew:

```
  $ rails g scaffold Word word_type_id:integer word_id:integer word_name:string
  $ rake db:migrate
```

I want to check if everything went right, so I run the rails console:

```
  $ rails console
  Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
  >> Word
  => Word(id: integer, word_name: string, word_type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Why is the old model still in here? Did I forget to undo something from the past?

#### EDIT/UPDATE

I've read up a little more and it seems like I forgot to reset the database. So now I use:

```
$ rake db:reset
```

The downside is that now I get this error when I try to migrate everything:

```
  $ rake db:migrate
  ==  CreateWords: migrating ====================================================
  -- create_table(:words)
  rake aborted!
  An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

  SQLite3::SQLException: table "words" already exists: CREATE TABLE "words" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "word_type_id" integer, "word_id" integer, "word_name" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Even though I read in some docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#resetting-the-database) that `rake db:reset` should drop all the old tables. Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NORMAL FLOW**

```
rails g scaffold Word word_name:string word_type_name:string
```

Creates controller, view, model, migration files

```
rake db:migrate
```

This is a rake task that will run through your ruby code of files in db/migrate/ and sets up database accordingly. In your case, this would create a `words` table with columns `word_name` and `word_type` .

Now, when you realize you have made a mistake in your scaffold, you need to first revert the database state. So, run

```
 rake db:rollback
```

This would undo the last migration, in your case the migration is creating the table `words` with the columns. Then you could remove all the scaffold files totally with

```
rails destroy scaffold Word
```

This will destroy all the files(view, models, migration).

Then you can proceed with your new scaffold,

```
 $ rails g scaffold Word word_type_id:integer word_id:integer word_name:string
 $ rake db:migrate
```

**IN YOUR STATE**

In your edit, you have used the command

```
  rake db:reset
```

This would only reset the values in the database i.e if you have values like

**DB**

```
  Words

 id name type

 1) Bike, noun

 2) Car, noun
```

`rake db:reset` would reset all the values in your db like this

**DB**

```
 Words

id name type
```

What you actually you need is to destroy the columns, if you had the migration file that created it, you could easily run `rake db:rollback` that would look for the last migration, migration file to undo the action.

I think you should have just started the project, so you could just drop the database with the command `rake db:drop` this would destroy all tables.

**DB**

```
  empty
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` which would run all your migrations

Answer (score 2):

Here, the problem is that you destroyed the scaffold Word but did not reverted migration, so old table is already created in database and did not drop.

Now you have generated scaffold again. But migration for his new scaffold will not be able to run because a table named words already exists:

You will not be able to drop table words using migrations because it has been deleted while destroying scaffold.

**If you don't fear to loose all your data then you may run:**

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

It will setup your db again with new changes.

**Or another way if you don't want to loose data in other tables,**

Drop table from database using database console in terminal from project directory:

```
rails dbconsole
>> drop table words;
>> exit

bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rollback your db with:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

**Attention**: You will loose all your data.

After that, change your migrations and run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

to generate the new database schema.